# Can't reference custom field in Section's Entry URI Format

Tags: sections, custom-field, entry-slug, uri

Craft 3.7.33

I've got a channel Section called "Stories", and a plain text custom field, `subTitle`, which I want to use in the Entry URI Format. Right now, that is `stories/{slug}`. When I change it to `stories/{slug}/{subTitle}`, Craft queues up a job to resave all the entries in the section, which completes very quickly... too quickly, around 33 entries updated per refresh cycle. Checking the frontend, and the URLs to the Stories entries, generated by `{{ entry.url }}`, have not changed.

If I change the Entry URI Format to something like `stories/{slug}/{author.username}`, the Resaving Story entries job queues up again, but this time running much more slowly, one entry at a time. And when the queue is done, the entry URLs in the frontend do indeed reflect the change.

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the entry URIs to use the value of the entry's `subTitle` field as well as the slug?

Comment: This might be no help, but I can at least say that the way you're doing it and everything you've described works fine for me. I tested just now in both Craft 3.7.60 and 4.4.12. There must be something else going on that is specific to your set up, or else you've made a typo somewhere.

Comment: You might want to check your queue logs (i.e. `storage/logs/queue.log`); might be a clue in there as to what's happening.